# How to extract a line equation that fit in the middle of a thick line contour

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, geometry, computer-vision

I have detected a line contour and I want to fit a line equation to describe it.

I tried least square fitting, but due to the perspective distortion, one end of the line is thicker and thus the line equation with drift to a side at one end.

I have also considered using zhang-suen thinning method, but such algorithm seems over-kill for a simple line

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try skeletoning the line? so that it will be one-pixel width at most.

Comment: Is there some non iterative approach of extracting skeleton? Zheng suen seems overkill

Comment: Can you provide a sample image of the line?

Comment: _Seems_ an overkill, or _it's_ an overkill? Have you profiled it?

Comment: I have updated an image

Comment: [this link](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-morphological-skeleton/) shows a simple algorithm in opencv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple and effective method is to compute the first **[principal component](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/making-sense-of-principal-component-analysis-eigenvectors-eigenvalues)** of the points on the line. Here is the code in matlab:

```matlab
% Read image
im = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJ5Si.png');

% Binarize image and extract indices of line pixels
imbw = imbinarize(rgb2gray(im), 'global');  % Threshold with Otsu's method
[y, x] = ind2sub(size(imbw), find(imbw));   % Get indices of line pixels

% Extract first principal component
C = cov(x, y);                              % Compute covariance of x and y
coeff = pcacov(C);                          % Compute eigenvectors of C
vector_xy = [coeff(1,1), coeff(2,1)];       % Get fist principal component

% Plot
figure; imshow(im); hold on
xx = vector_xy(1) * [-1 1] * size(imbw,2) + mean(x(:));
yy = vector_xy(2) * [-1 1] * size(imbw,2) + mean(y(:));
plot(xx,yy,'c','LineWidth',2)
axis on, legend('Principal Axis','Location','NorthWest')
```

[image]

You can obtain the coefficients of the line equation `y = a*x + b` with

```
a = vector_xy(2) / vector_xy(1);
b = mean(y(:)) - a * mean(x(:));
```

Comment: Would ICA performs better since there are some noise in non-orthogonal direction?

Comment: That's well possible. I guess you have to try it. You can also try to remove the noise through morphological filtering.